# Touch and focus on 3GS with showsCameraControls = NO

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-3gs

I`m developing a program that makes use of UIImagePicker custom class made by me, and the thing is I want to be able to use the manual-focus feature on the 3GS (the part where the user points where the camera should focus) and at the same time to use custom overlay view.
I`ve set showsCameraControls to NO so that the images could be taken programmatically and to make use of my own custom overlay but when the camera controls are hidden so is the manual focus feature.
I even got to the point where I subclassed UIApplication to catch the touch events and for the ImagePicker to continue to receive the events in order to execute the manual focus feature. And it worked with showsCameraControls = YES but that`s not what I want.

- Is there a way to invoke focus on the 3GS?
- Is there a way that camera controls are hidden but not the view (viewController) which is handling the touch events?
- Is there a way for me to use the default camera controls (with an overlay) but still take consecutive pictures programmatically?

I`ll be very grateful for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no programmatic control over autofocus. When the camera controls are hidden, there is no way to invoke focus. ([Source from the Apple developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/135339#135339), where the OP (or someone else) posted the same question).